# mysql get value in a column to be divided on a cumulative average

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have values in the range of 1 to 4 in column A. i would like my column B to be a return of the values from column A on a cumulative method.

For example, i would like the value in column B id 1 to be the value of A with id 1 divided by the Average of id 1 and 0 of column A.

Or in column B id 2 to be the value of A with id 2 divided by the Average of values with id 1,2 and 0 of column A.

```
 id    A   B
  _    _   _

  0     1  1/1
  1     2  2/(AVG(A1,A0))
  2     3  3/(AVG(A1,A2,A0))
  3     4  4/(AVG(A1,A2,A3,A0))
```

here is my code:

```
update f
set f.B =f.A/(SELECT AVG(f.A) FROM (SELECT f.A from f WHERE f.id <= f.id));

But i get an error: Every derived table must have its own alias
```

if I have another column C which is identical to A,will this work?

```
UPDATE 
    f
SET 
    f.B =(f.A/(
        SELECT AVG(f.A) 
        FROM (
            SELECT f.A  
            FROM f 
            WHERE f.id <= f.id
            ) as t )
        as temp)
          +
        f.C/(
        SELECT AVG(f.C) 
        FROM (
            SELECT f.C  
            FROM f 
            WHERE f.id <= f.id
            ) as t2 
        ) as temp2)/2;
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0):

your tables need to have an alias try this

with your additional question.. you need to do the selects first then do the division and addition with the alias. like so:

```
UPDATE 
    f,
    (
        SELECT AVG(f.A) 
        FROM (
            SELECT f.A  
            FROM f 
            WHERE f.id <= f.id
        ) as t 
    ) as temp,
    (
        SELECT AVG(f.C) 
        FROM (
            SELECT f.C  
            FROM f 
            WHERE f.id <= f.id
        ) as t2 
    ) as temp2
SET 
    f.B =(f.A/temp) + (f.C/temp2)/2;
```

Comment: I get an error: `error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as temp)+ `

Comment: @jenn ok i just edited... you need to do the selects first... I don't know what you are trying to accomplish so there may be something wrong with the calculations in the SET but you should be able to easily figure it out from there

Comment: nope :/ but i got the ans here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819681/mysql-moving-average-calculation-using-case/23820181#23820181  it is slightly modified.